# Best practices of keeping Firefox profile on ramdisk

Tags: linux, firefox, lvm, ramdisk, firefox-profile

Having plenty of RAM, I'd like to use it to speed up the browser.

Goals:

1. Have profile and cache completely in memory, so HDD is not used much while browsing and `fsync`s don't reach actual HDD or filesystems.
2. In background, keep updating HDD copy of the profile, so that in case of sudden outage not more than X minutes of browsing are lost;
3. Keep backups consistent (without broken sqlite databases etc.)

I.e. trade some free memory and some recency of browsing session in case of crash for speed.

How to organize such scheme?

My current idea is like this:

1. Use zram to create a ramdisk; `modprobe zram`;
2. Create LVM volume on it `losetup /dev/zram0 /dev/loop1; pvcreate /dev/loop1; ...; mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal /dev/mapper/ffvg-ffvol`;
3. Place Firefox profile on this volume;
4. Periodically (each N minutes) create LVM snapshot and backup it to HDD, then remove the snapshot.

This (especially LVM part) looks a bit heavyweight for the task. Are there better/more established/simpler ways for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configured a volume for Firefox according idea in question.

- At boot up two zram devices get created. Content of a HDD volume is copied to the first. Second is used as copy-on-write device for snapshots;
- Firefox profile directory is symlinked to the volume kept in zram0.
- Periodically a script (below) creates snapshot of the in-memory device (using zram1 as copy-on-write), snapshot of the HDD volume and copies memory snapshot to HDD volume.

Each update takes about 10 seconds (in case of little number of changes); full update is 40 seconds.

Update script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

SOURCE_DEVICE=/dev/zram0
COW_DEVICE=/dev/zram1
SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME=ffsnap

DESTINATION_VG=cryptie3
DESTINATION_VOL=ff

HASH_FILE=/tmp/ff.md5


MS=$(blockdev --getsize "$SOURCE_DEVICE")
WS=$(blockdev --getsize "$COW_DEVICE")
MN=$(printf '%d:%d' `stat -c '0x%t 0x%T' "$SOURCE_DEVICE"`)
WN=$(printf '%d:%d' `stat -c '0x%t 0x%T' "$COW_DEVICE"`)

dmsetup create $SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME --table "0 $MS snapshot $MN $WN N 8"
trap "dmsetup remove --force --retry $SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME" EXIT

T=$(date "+%s")

lvcreate $DESTINATION_VG/$DESTINATION_VOL --snapshot --name ${DESTINATION_VOL}_$T -L 100M

# You can just use "cat /dev/mapper/$SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME > /dev/mapper/$DESTINATION_VG-$DESTINATION_VOL" here if you don't want to use hashed_update

if [ -e "$HASH_FILE" ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/hashed_update /dev/mapper/$SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME            "$HASH_FILE"  \
                                 /dev/mapper/$DESTINATION_VG-$DESTINATION_VOL "${HASH_FILE}".new 65536
    mv "${HASH_FILE}".new "$HASH_FILE"
else
    /usr/local/bin/hashed_update /dev/mapper/$SOURCE_SNAPSHOT_NAME NULL   \
                                 /dev/mapper/$DESTINATION_VG-$DESTINATION_VOL "$HASH_FILE" 65536
fi

lvremove --force ${DESTINATION_VG}/${DESTINATION_VOL}_$T
```

hashed_update is here: https://github.com/vi/hashed_update

Some update: 1. Don't fotget to mount `SOURCE_DEVICE` though `snapshot-origin`, not directly; 2. Now I use manual management of destination snapshots with persistent CoW zone using `dmsetup` instead of repeated lvcreate/lvremove.

Still looking for ideas how to improve it or for established solutions I failed to find.

Comment: FTR, https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon is around since 2012, however with practical use within our https://github.com/fsfw-dresden/usb-live-linux (to go easy on flash memory) we noticed recurring corruption of the various firefox sqlite files, so disabled it for the time being.

Comment: @eMPee584 I used a similar solution, https://github.com/ecdye/zram-config, which use zram+overlayfs and sync content back with a cron job every night. I put two sqlite db in volume of dockered app in zram. Every day, after syncing, the apps complain about "can not write to db". My solution is to stop these two app before sync and restart after. While sycn operation seems to modify user prilivage or ownership of the volume folder, I add another chmod command after sync. Now the two app work well.